# WooCommerce | Only show variations which are in stock from different attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We are trying to only show the products which are in stock for the specific variation. We are getting a parameter in the url like `/categorie/herenschoenen/?filter_size=13-5`.

Currently we have this function, but it always shows no results:

```
/**
 * Size variant filter by stock
 */

function vm_woocommerce_product_query( $q, $instance ) {
    $product = wc_get_product($q->get('post_parent'));

    // Check if the 'filter_size' parameter exists in the URL
    if (isset($_GET['filter_size'])) {
        $filter_size = $_GET['filter_size'];
        
        // Modify the query to only show products with the parameter value as a variation that is in stock
        $meta_query = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => '_stock_status',
                'value' => 'outofstock',
                'compare' => '!='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => '_variation_description',
                'value' => $filter_size,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        );
        $q->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'vm_woocommerce_product_query', 10, 2 );
```

So the problem is that the filter list comes from attribute `pa_size`, but the variations it self are coming from multiple attributes like:

`pa_0_one_size, pa_1_36_t_m_42_eu, pa_3_36_t_m_42_us, pa_4_39_t_m_48_us`

So we have to check if the paramter value exists as a variation and then check if it is in stock. But we can't get it to work.

Does anybody know how to get this to work?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps modify code to check for the attribute value in the variation description instead of just checking for the specific value.

- gets all the variation IDs that match
- modifies query to only show product variations

Maybe this can work for you:

```
function vm_woocommerce_product_query( $q, $instance ) {
    // Check if the 'filter_size' parameter exists in the URL
    if ( isset( $_GET['filter_size'] ) ) {
        $filter_size = $_GET['filter_size'];
        $attribute_taxonomy = 'pa_size'; // Change this to the attribute taxonomy slug you want to filter by

        // Get the product variations that match the attribute value in the variation description and are in stock
        $variation_ids = wc_get_products(
            array(
                'type'       => 'variation',
                'status'     => 'publish',
                'limit'      => -1,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key'     => '_stock_status',
                        'value'   => 'outofstock',
                        'compare' => '!='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'     => '_variation_description',
                        'value'   => sprintf( ':"%s";', $filter_size ),
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
                ),
                'parent'     => $q->get( 'post_parent' ),
                'return'     => 'ids',
                'paginate'   => false,
            )
        );

        // Modify the query to only show products that have variations that are in stock for the specified attribute value
        $meta_query = array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'     => '_stock_status',
                'value'   => 'outofstock',
                'compare' => '!='
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => '_variation_description',
                'value'   => sprintf( ':"%s";', $filter_size ),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key'            => '_variation_id',
                'value'          => $variation_ids,
                'compare'        => 'IN',
                'type'           => 'numeric',
                'meta_query'     => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key'     => sprintf( 'attribute_%s', $attribute_taxonomy ),
                        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'     => sprintf( 'attribute_%s', $attribute_taxonomy ),
                        'value'   => '',
                        'compare' => '!='
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'vm_woocommerce_product_query', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is not working. The variation description is empty. It needs to check the variation name, not the description. I tried some thing but still can't get it to work. Is it possible u have another solution?